# 特定のネットワークから名前解決できない

Tags: network, dns, amazon-route53

**背景と事象**
AWSを利用してワードプレスブログをはじめようと環境構築を行っておりますが、
自宅のNW内にある端末からブログサイトへのドメインの名前解決ができずアクセスができません。
・DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN：Chrome
・DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE：Brave

例）http://example.com
　補足）たまにアクセスできますが、再度リダイレクトをするとアクセス不可となってしまいます。

構成は、Route53、Lightsailのみとなります。

**各種情報**
・ドメインはRoute53で登録（example.com）
・LightsailのStaticIPを利用（111.22.33.4）
・ホストゾーンはRoute53で作成（Lightsail側からも作成をして試してみましたが解決せず）
・aレコード作成済（example.com → 111.22.33.4）
・StaticIPではアクセスは可能（http://111.22.33.4）
・別のNW（会社NWで試してみました）からはドメインでアクセス可能。（http://example.com）

なぜか自宅のNWからのみ名前解決ができないように見えます。
1日調べたり自宅NWのプロバイダにも相談しましたが、解決の糸口が見えず。
どなたかお力添えよろしくお願いします。